# How to center ion side menu images/text

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

[image]

```
 <ion-nav-back-button class="no-text">
            </ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-more-vertical" menu-toggle="right">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="fabContent"></ion-nav-view>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" ng-class="{expanded: isExpanded}" ></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="dark-bg expanded">
           <span class="avatar" style="background: url('img/crown.jpg'); background-size: cover; "></span> 
            <h2>Thronester</h2>
        </ion-header-bar>
```

How would I center the image and text without using CSS? I'm trying to get the circular image and the text below it to center in the black. I've tried a lot of things and didn't get results.

Comment: Did you have the chance to look into my answer? Any feedback would be appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't provided any `css` so I can only give you my option.

I would customize the `<ion-header-bar>` inside `<ion-side-menu>` this way:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-profile">
    <div class="profile">
        <img class="profile-picture" src="http://ionicframework.com/img/docs/mcfly.jpg" />
        <h3 class="name">Thronester</h3>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

using this css:

```
.bar.bar-profile {
    background-color: #444;
    height: 170px;
}

.bar .profile {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.profile .name {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.profile-picture {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.menu .has-header
{
    top: 169px;
}
```

[image]

the final result can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LVOSoY5wPqQpv7HERpAV?p=preview).

Comment: Hey lefty, your solution was too complex for such a simple thing. I didn't want to implement so much css for this. This question was asked while I was working on it for a hackathon. I asked someone near me about it and they used inspect element to modify its exact position by pixels for simplicity sake. I used this line of code to give it a fixed position: <span class="avatar" style="background: url('img/crown.jpg'); background-size: cover; left:82px"></span>

Comment: Lefty - thats a great solution, but I wonder if there is any benefit to doing all of it within the ion-header-bar. I just got rid of that and placed a centered picture with some padding right in the ion-content section at the top before the list. Seems to be much easier. Thoughts?

Comment: @7200rpm: if you provide a plunker I could compare it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

[image: centered ionic2 side menu image/text]

For >ionic2

```
<ion-card text-center class="hide-card">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="custom-avatar"/>
    <h2>Victorcodex</h2>
    <p>Have some p tag here</p>
    <p>I am the third guy inline here</p>
    <hr>
</ion-card>

.hide-card {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
}

.custom-avatar {
  height: 30vw;
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just to center the text and images you want, then you could use the HTML  tags, particularly if the CSS text-align:center; does not work. Often, it has not worked for me, and I have used the  tags.